# How to display lines as dynamic columns with other values?

Tags: mysql

I want to display orders item that have the collect_id = 2
And I want to display all the fields related to each order_item as columns with values.

These are the tables and the result :

```
+-------------------------------+
|         order_item            |
+-------------------------------+
| oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id |
| 1         100         2       |
| 2         30          2       |
| 3         55          3       |
| 4         70          4       |
| 5         220         2       |
| 6         300         4       |
+-------------------------------+

+-----------------------------------+
|            field_value            |
+-----------------------------------+
| v_value    v_fk_field_id oi_fk_id |
|  Peter             1        1     |
|  Lagaf             2        1     |
|  Football          3        1     |
|  Male              4        1     |
|  12345678          5        1     |
|  Frank             1        2     |
|  Loran             2        2     |
|  Tennis            3        2     |
|  Male              4        2     |
|  11223658          5        2     |
|  Nathali           1        5     |
|  Waton             2        5     |
|  Reading           3        5     |
+-----------------------------------+

oi_fk_id : foreign key ref(order_item.oi_id)
v_fk_field_id : foreign key ref(field.f_id)

+--------------------+
|       field        |
+--------------------+
| f_id      f_label  |
| 1          surname |
| 2          name    |
| 3          hobbies |
| 4          sex     |
| 5          phone   |
+--------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   Result                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  oi_id  oi_price oi_collect_id surname    name    hobbies    sex    phone   |
|  1         100         2        Peter     Lagaf   Football   Male  12345678 |
|  2         30          2        Frank     Loran    Tennis    Male  11223658 |
|  5         220         2       Nathali    Waton   Reading    null    null   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Important : The table field does not contain only these 5 fields (name, surname, hobbies, sex, phone), but it can contain many others, that the developper may not know, same thing for the correspondant value on the table 'field_value'.

PS : I didn't make field labels as columns in a table because they are dynamic and not limited, and in the front end application, the user can add new fields as he want.

Comment: So what is your question? you want to display lines?

Comment: Shouldn't there be, in the field_value table, the oi_fk_id equal to 5 in the last three rows? Based on the target result you provided?

Comment: Yes, it must be equal to 5.

Comment: I want to display the result given, the lines on the table 'field_value' will be columns on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of dynamic pivoting to get the results:

```
SELECT      GROUP_CONCAT(t.line)
    FROM    (
        SELECT      CONCAT('MAX(IF(t.l=''', f.f_label, ''',t.v,NULL)) AS ', f.f_label) AS line
            FROM    field f
        ) AS t
    INTO @dynamic;

SELECT      CONCAT('SELECT t.oi_id, t.oi_price, t.oi_collect_id,', 
            @dynamic, 
            ' FROM ( SELECT oi.*, f.f_label AS l, fv.v_value AS v FROM order_item oi JOIN field_value fv ON fv.oi_fk_id = oi.oi_id JOIN field f ON f.f_id = fv.v_fk_field_id WHERE oi.oi_collect_id = 2 ) AS t GROUP BY t.oi_id;')
    INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

However it is limited by [GROUP_CONCAT function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

> The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024. The value can be set higher, although the effective maximum length of the return value is constrained by the value of max_allowed_packet.

EDIT - Why MAX function is required?

To solve the given problem, we are creating a dynamic query, based on the content of the `field` table.

For the given exemplary data, the query without use of MAX function would be:

```
SELECT      t.oi_id,
            t.oi_price,
            t.oi_collect_id,
            IF(t.l='surname', t.v, NULL) AS surname,
            IF(t.l='name', t.v, NULL) AS name,
            IF(t.l='hobbies', t.v, NULL) AS hobbies,
            IF(t.l='sex', t.v, NULL) AS sex,
            IF(t.l='phone', t.v, NULL) AS phone
    FROM    (
        SELECT      oi.*,
                    f.f_label AS l,
                    fv.v_value as V
            FROM    order_item oi
            JOIN    field_value fv
                ON  fv.oi_fk_id = oi.oi_id
            JOIN    field f
                ON  f.f_id = fv.v_fk_field_id
            WHERE   oi.oi_collect_id = 2
        ) AS t;
```

Which wouldd result in:

```
+-------+----------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+------+----------+
| oi_id | oi_price | oi_collect_id | surname | name  | hobbies  | sex  | phone    |
+-------+----------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+------+----------+
|     1 |      100 |             2 | Peter   | NULL  | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     2 |       30 |             2 | Frank   | NULL  | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     5 |      220 |             2 | Nathali | NULL  | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     1 |      100 |             2 | NULL    | Lagaf | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     2 |       30 |             2 | NULL    | Loran | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     5 |      220 |             2 | NULL    | Waton | NULL     | NULL | NULL     |
|     1 |      100 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | Football | NULL | NULL     |
|     2 |       30 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | Tennis   | NULL | NULL     |
|     5 |      220 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | Reading  | NULL | NULL     |
|     1 |      100 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | NULL     | Male | NULL     |
|     2 |       30 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | NULL     | Male | NULL     |
|     1 |      100 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | NULL     | NULL | 12345678 |
|     2 |       30 |             2 | NULL    | NULL  | NULL     | NULL | 11223658 |
+-------+----------+---------------+---------+-------+----------+------+----------+
```

This is an intermediate result, where each row consists of value for one `field` and NULL for the others. The `MAX` function together with a `GROUP BY` clause is used to combine multiple rows concerning one `order item` in such a way, that it chooses non null values. It could be replaced by MIN function, which will also favor existing values over null.

Comment: A 'distinct' is missing before "CONCAT('MAX ...", thanks for all.

Comment: If field table contains duplicate labels then yes, distinct is also required. No problem

Comment: What do exactly "Max" ?

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question?

Comment: I mean what do exactly the function "Max" in the code : CONCAT('MAX(IF(t.l=''', f.f_label, ''',t.v,NULL)) AS '

Comment: I edited the answer with some explanation. If you have any more questions or you think it is still unclear, please ask, and I will try to clarify better.